# How can I write c++ main function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, program-entry-point

can I write c++ main function without return integer value?
I am using visual studio 2010.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout <<"In main function" << endl;  
    //return 0; 
}    `
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings with this code?

Comment: No. I didn't get any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since the release of C99, you can skip the return value of `main()`.

Let's look at C++11

**3.6.1**

> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function
>   (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling
>   std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control reaches
>   the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is
>   that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Comment: What does C99 have to do with C++?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I meant all compilers after succeeding C99 ( whether it be C or C++ ) will put return type as 0, or is that wrong? Please correct me if I was wrong on this part.

Comment: Can the return value of `main` be casted?  For example: `(void) main(void)`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, AFAIK, No ( tried compiling as well, and it didn't compile )

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ Standard (3.6.1 Main function)

> 5 A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main
>   function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and
>   calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. **If control
>   reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the
>   effect is that of executing**
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Thus the shortest C++ program is

```
int main() {}
```

Comment: `int main(){}` is 1 byte shorter ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With the VS2010 compiler, you actually can declare it as `void main()` if you're not interested in returning a value.

Though this isn't a C++ standard compliant feature.

Comment: You are wrong. main shall have return type int.

Comment: The compiler that comes with VS 2010 allows declaring `main` as `void`.

Comment: @Cristik: That is irrelevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the  asker said that he is using VS2010, so I gave an answer that suits that environment, as VS allows you to declare `void` mains, thus the developer doesn't need to type the `return` statement.

Comment: That you don't need to type the `return` statement is unrelated to this notion that you can change the return _type_. The two are distinct considerations. C++ allows you to omit `return 0`; it does not allow you to change `int` to `void`. I don't really care that some implementation has an extension: the question is clearly asking about C++ (with IDE provided as additional, contextual information).

Comment: That's your opinion and I respect it, I just wanted to let the asker know that  there is a workaround to his `can I write c++ main function without return integer value?` question. Also the good people that edited my answer added a clarification that this is not standard, so I don't think this answer would hurt anyone. That doesn't mean though that people should agree with it :)